# age calculation in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

My data frame looks like -

```
id       dob 
1       13/01/1978  
2       03/08/1957
3       22/12/1977
```

I want to calculate age based on 'dob' column.

```
id       dob             age
1       13/01/1978        43    
2       03/08/1957        64
3       22/12/1976        44
```

I have done the below code but its not working

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
data['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dob'])
data['age'] = (now.date() - data['dob']).astype('<m8[Y]')
```

Comment: df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob'])
now = pd.to_datetime('now')(now - df['dob']).astype('<m8[Y]')

Comment: @orbit - DateParseError: Invalid date specified (0/1)...not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
d = { 'Id': [1,2,3],
      'dob': ['13/01/1978', '03/08/1957', '22/12/1977'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['dob']= pd.to_datetime(df['dob'])
now = datetime.datetime.now()
df['age'] = df['dob'].apply(lambda x: now.year - x.year)


#Output:

    Id  dob         age
0   1   1978-01-13  43
1   2   1957-03-08  64
2   3   1977-12-22  44
```

This version is more precise because based on days instead of year:

```
df['age_2'] =  df['dob'].apply(lambda x: int((now - x).days / 365.25) )

#Output: 

    Id   dob        age age_2
0   1   1978-01-13  43  43
1   2   1957-03-08  64  64
2   3   1977-12-22  44  43
```

Comment: It's works - but what if it's 4 month, and the dob have birthday in February?
It should be day specific i suppose.

Comment: Yes. Day based version is more precise as I mentioned. Use whichever works for you and please accept the answer if you find it useful.